# How do I implement a delay on jQuery keyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'm making a list filter and want a delay in case the user is a fast typer.  Looking at different solutions for similar questions hasn't helped me and I don't understand the logic they implement.

This is my current code:

```
$.fn.filterList = function(){   
    var inputFilter = $(this);
    var list        = $('#' + inputFilter.data('list'));
    var listItems    = list.children('li');

    inputFilter.keyup(function(){

        setTimeout(function () {
            var term = inputFilter.val().toLowerCase();

            listItems.each(function(i, e){
                var city = ($(e).text()).toLowerCase();

                if(city.startsWith(term)){
                    console.log(city);
                }
            });
        }, 800);
    });

};

$('.my-input').filterList();
```

The problem with this is that it will trigger on each keyup, no matter how fast the user types.

How can I implement a delay so that it does not trigger for each `keyup`?

Comment: `keyup` is meant to trigger for each key released. You can only control what you do in the event handler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery function to delay sometime after Keyup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577429/jquery-function-to-delay-sometime-after-keyup)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On each successive `keypress` you need to clear the previous timer so that the function only fires X milliseconds after typing ends. Try this:

```js
var timer;

inputFilter.keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    var term = inputFilter.val().toLowerCase();

    listItems.each(function(i, e) {
      var city = $(e).text().toLowerCase();
      if (city.startsWith(term)) {
        console.log(city);
      }
    });
  }, 800);
});
```

Here's a simplified working example:

```js
var timer;
$('#foo').keypress(function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
  }, 800);
});
```

```css
div { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo" />
<div>You stopped typing 1 second ago</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Now I know :) By the way, I found the same solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577429/jquery-function-to-delay-sometime-after-keyup

Comment: You will need to leak the timer variable to the parent scope: `timer = setTimeout(...` (No `var`)

Answer (score 1):

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

inputFilter.keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
      var term = inputFilter.val().toLowerCase();

            listItems.each(function(i, e){
                var city = ($(e).text()).toLowerCase();

                if(city.startsWith(term)){
                    console.log(city);
                }
            });
    }, 800 );
});
```

Comment: What's the point of putting an anonymous function call in an anonymous function call inside a function call when you can just use `setTimeout()` directly? The encapsulation makes no sense.

Comment: when you need more delays for your project you can use this delay function by passing the function and the delay time. For just one delay call it's not efficient but still effective.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="inputtext" />
```

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#inputtext').keyup(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    alert("Hi");
                }, 5000);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -4):

On each keyup count clicks and after some of them trigger function.
Pro-tip: And use

```
.on('keyup', function(){}).
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem when the user searches for long strings. The goal is to fire an event when the user has finished